# Encryption of the audio file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, cryptography, commoncrypto

I want to encrypt the audio file; how do I achieve it in the iPhone? Is there any framework to get this done?

This is the code I am using to encrypt the file,

```
NSData *inputData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localfilePath.path]; 

NSString *encryptKey=[NSString stringWithString:@"nywleS"];





  CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
                  NSData *encrypted = [inputData dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:encryptKey initializationVector:@"Selwyn" options:0 error:&status];


NSData *decryptedData = [outputData decryptedAES256DataUsingKey:encryptKey error:nil];
```

But the original file size becomes less after encryption in CBS mode. And also after decryption, it's the same size as encrypted.

Comment: Keep in mind that anybody determined can still get your audio file, this is mostly going to prevent users from casually copying it out of the .ipa after syncing with iTunes.  That said, you might be able to achieve the same results with a simple XOR or affine cipher.  (If the AES route turns out to not be performant enough)

Comment: do you have any sample code for the implementation to the reference that i can view

Comment: added as an answer, please don't accept though - as it doesn't answer your original question ;)

Answer (score 1):

iOS supports [CommonCrypto](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/CryptographicServices/CryptographicServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976-CH3-SW1) (just like Mac OSX does). That will let you encrypt and decrypt any type of data, including audio.

There are several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480883/how-to-use-common-crypto) on how to use CommonCrypto in your applications.

Comment: can you please post me an sample code for encryption using AES encryption and decryption.

Comment: @Selwyn Apple has a sample for this available @ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: i am using the common crypto but i want to work on CBC mode and i am not able to select the cbc mode.

Comment: @Selwyn **CBC** is the default mode (so you should not have any problem to select it). Note that using CBC requires you to provide an IV.

Comment: I have applied that mode and iv and it gets encrypted and decrypted on the iPhone sucessfully but its not encrypted by the .net code i am using to decrypt.

Comment: @Selwyn you never showed any .NET code, nor even mentioned it, in your question. We can't help you without details. Also note that Stackoverflow is not a forum or a chat (see FAQ). Adding missing/requested information is fine, changing the question is not.

Comment: I have to encrypt the audio file in iPhone and then upload it via a web service and then one decrypt or utility written in .net is decrypting the audio file. I have used the normal decrypt or code in .net to decrypt .But i am getting an error as Padding is invalid.Could you please help me in this since i am stuck  at this point i am not getting the issue related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

poupou's answer should ultimately get credit, as he is answering the original question.  I'm posting this as an answer since reference code was asked of me in comments above:

From [Obfuscate / Encrypt a String](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/obfuscation-encryption-of-string-nsstring.html), modified for NSData:

```
- (NSData *)obfuscate:(NSData *)data withKey:(NSString *)key
{
  NSData *result = [data mutableCopy];

  // Get pointer to data to obfuscate
  char *dataPtr = (char *) [result mutableBytes];

  // Get pointer to key data
  char *keyData = (char *) [[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes];

  // Points to each char in sequence in the key
  char *keyPtr = keyData;
  int keyIndex = 0;

  // For each character in data, xor with current value in key
  for (int x = 0; x < [data length]; x++) 
  {
    // Replace current character in data with 
    // current character xor'd with current key value.
    // Bump each pointer to the next character
    *dataPtr = *dataPtr++ ^ *keyPtr++; 

    // If at end of key data, reset count and 
    // set key pointer back to start of key value
    if (++keyIndex == [key length])
      keyIndex = 0, keyPtr = keyData;
  }

  return [result autorelease];
}
```

Again, this is intended to prevent casual copying of the audio file (as mentioned in my comments), not as a secure end-to-end encryption technique.